# Is there any drag and drop CSS based layout generation tool?

Tags: css

I have seen 'headways' which is a wordpress framework use this technique to easily create css layout based on 960gs. Is there any such software/tool for generating normal css layout?

Comment: How is this programming-related? This is about an application.

Comment: In this kind of situation, I tend to tell myself we really miss a good search engine nowadays. If only... **[Google](http://www.google.com)** existed.

Comment: @Chris Fletcher lol that was very funny!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.pagecolumn.com/

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/builder/

http://csscreator.com/version2/pagelayout.php

http://www.cssportal.com/layout-generator/

http://grids.heroku.com/

http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/

and there are many grid systems to choose from (many are respnsive) 960, 1140, blueprint, gold en grid, bootstrap, etc. etc. etc

Comment: Thanks, that's an exhaustive list. I find http://www.pagecolumn.com/ to be the best among the list you mentioned above.

Answer (score -3):

Yes did one, for generating normal css and html layout using DnD:
[HTML CSS layout generator online](http://www.blended-menu.com/html-layout-builder.html)
Same for generating pure css and html menus:
[HTML CSS menu generator online](http://www.blended-menu.com/)